# Sending an application (apk) through NFC

Tags: installation, apk, nfc

Is it possible to install the application to another device using NFC? The application is not in Google Play store.

If it is possible, how can I do this?

Comment: If you're not fixed on NFC, you could share it e.g. via Bluetooth and then side-load it on the other device, provided you enabled "allow unknown sources" in that device's settings.

Comment: +1 to Izzy's comment, unless the app is small you'd probably want to send it via another medium as NFC's data rate is pretty slow. Still an interesting question though.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the app available as an apk file, you can use the app [NFC Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abhi.sendfilewifi) to share it. It uses Android Beam to share any file (NFC is used to set up a Bluetooth connection to transfer the actual file).